Error using Tensorflow in Python: google.protobuf
I am trying to run a Python script in Anaconda environment on Windows using Python 3.8.20 and Tensorflow 2.10. The following error occurs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder_test.py", line 20, in <module>
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
File "D:\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 23, in <module>
from object_detection.builders import anchor_generator_builder
File "D:\models\research\object_detection\builders\anchor_generator_builder.py", line 26, in <module>
from object_detection.protos import anchor_generator_pb2
File "D:\models\research\object_detection\protos\anchor_generator_pb2.py", line 9, in <module>
from google.protobuf import runtime_version as _runtime_version
ImportError: cannot import name 'runtime_version' from 'google.protobuf' (C:\Users\pcmsi\anaconda3\envs\tf_env\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\__init__.py)

How do I fix it?

looks like a compatibility issue. check version of protobuf
If your protobuf version is 4.x or higher, it might be incompatible with TensorFlow 2.10 which typically works best with protobuf 3.x.
if indeed the versions are incompatible, either upgrade TF or downgrade protobuf to 3.20

Thanks but it doesn't work still

your log shows you're using a different env for anaconda. did you try doing this in the shell for that environment?

Yes, I was in the correct environment

The error is related to incompatibilities between protobuf and TensorFlow. To check if TensorFlow is correctly installed in your environment.Import TensorFlow and check its version:
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

Also check the currently installed version of protobuf:
pip show protobuf

You may need to downgrade protobuf to a compatible version. TensorFlow 2.10 typically works well with protobuf 3.19.x.
To install protobuf 3.19.6, run:
pip install protobuf==3.19.6

If you need more info about getting started with python in Tensorflow, you can see here: https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2023/01/getting-started-with-python-in-tensorflow.html
